# How separate between days on the week view with fullcalendar react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a `FullCalendar` :

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

// must manually import the stylesheets for each plugin

import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";


<FullCalendar 
                   locale={frLocale}
                   allDaySlot={false}
            defaultView="timeGridWeek"
            nowIndicator={true}
            hiddenDays={[0]}
            slotDuration='00:45:00'
            minTime="07:00:00"
            maxTime="20:00:00"
            slotEventOverlap={false}
            handleWindowResize={true}
            header={{
              left: "prev,next today",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
            }}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ]}
            ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
            events={this.state.events}
            displayEventEnd={true}
          />
```

when I run  it, I get:

[image]

I want to separate between days like a yellow line :

[image]

My `package.json` :

[image]

I try to add this css :

```
.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-time-grid tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.667);
}

.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-widget-content {
  border-right: 2px solid #EE7 !important;
}

.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-widget-content:first-child {
  border-right: inherit !important;
}
```

But it doesn't working and I want the background color of the calendar is white.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Which version of full-calendar are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl v4

Comment: @CodeLover it works on my side. https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-react-8r38x

Comment: @DragonWhite what did you add? I try that and it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using Bootstrap, the grid shows up fine. The example below uses an identical configuration to your `<FullCalendar>` attributes.

**Edit:** Added the Bootstrap theme and the columns are still separated.

```js
plugins: [ 'bootstrap',  ... ],
themeSystem: 'bootstrap'
```

**Edit #2:** If you *REALLY* want to style the columns, you can try this:

```css
.fc-widget-content {
  border-right: 2px solid #EE7 !important; /* Line thickness is 2px to better show */
}
.fc-widget-content:first-child {
  border-right: inherit !important; /* Revert the first child */
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    locale: 'fr',
    allDaySlot: false,
    nowIndicator: true,
    hiddenDays: [0],
    slotDuration: '00:45:00',
    minTime: "07:00:00",
    maxTime: "20:00:00",
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    handleWindowResize: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    displayEventEnd: true,
    header : {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
    }
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-time-grid tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.667);
}

.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-widget-content {
  border-right: 2px solid #EE7 !important;
}

.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-widget-content:first-child {
  border-right: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/bootstrap/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/core/locales/fr.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/bootstrap/main.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I need to use FullCalendar with Reactjs

Comment: @CodeLover It does not matter if it's React of plain JS. The final presentation will be the same. I just set up the `FullCalendar` config to use your attributes. It's literally the same thing. My result matches Dragon White's React sandbox example.

Comment: @CodeLover Updated with a CSS rule.

Comment: Thank you, but, the border line is here just for the gray row and not the white background, and I want the background of the all rows are white. I try that https://ibb.co/prKysQy and when I run it, I get https://ibb.co/LgZXRHJ

Comment: @CodeLover The column lines are on an absolute table that sits atop the rows. The calendar is three tables stacked on top of each other. This may be too difficult to add vertical lines for specific rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203223/discussion-between-codelover-and-mr-polywhirl).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve that by adding:

```
.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-time-grid tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0 !important;
}
.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-time-grid tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0 !important;
}

.fc-widget-content {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important; /* Line thickness is 2px to better show */
}
.fc-timeGrid-view .fc-widget-content:first-child{
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

```
.fc .fc-scrollgrid-section .fc-timegrid-cols table {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I'm using fullcalendar 5.11.0 with bootstrap 4.6.1, loaded with webpack. Apparently there is a rule which has something to do with making the grid scrollable that sets the column height to 1px. This rule resets it to the original 100%.